# Behaviour of capacitor while charging

Tags: capacitor, ac

[image]

When a capacitor is applied with an AC Wave in a circuit containing only capacitor, it charges to its peak value between the time period of 0 to 90 degrees. My doubt is that what happens between the time period 90 to 180 degrees i.e. when the voltage starts decreasing from peak to zero. I understand that there is no dissipating element in the circuit therefore charge will not decay as time constant RC is zero. But still I was eager to know what happens at that time interval i.e. 90 to 180 degrees.

Comment: The charge will decay; it'll go back into the voltage source.

Comment: No. It remains constant. What you are saying happens b/w 180 to 270 degrees.

Comment: Remember that current and voltage are out of phase in a capacitor.

Comment: I know that by 90 degrees.

Comment: @JohnCena, if the voltage on the capacitor falls, then the charge is dropping. \$Q=CV\$. You can't change \$V\$ without changing \$Q\$.

Comment: If your source is not capable of sinking current with a positive voltage output, then it isn't capable of producing the given voltage waveform across a capacitor.

Comment: The waveform you showed is not the waveform of the voltage across the capacitor in a peak detector. In fact, this is the first time you've mentioned a "peak detector". Why do you expect us to answer the question about a peak detector if you never mention a peak detector in the question text?

Comment: Hint: your question says only a source and a capacitor are connect.  A peak detector requires more than a source and a capacitor.

Comment: Hint 2: Calling people "sir" sounds so over-the-top polite that people will consider it sarcastic and rude.

Comment: Yes, a diode is also required. So people are trying to help you understand the circuit you asked about: "a circuit containing only capacitor". We didn't know until you mentioned it that you had any interest in a circuit that also contains a diode.

Comment: If you want to change the question you're asking, you should edit the question text. (Nowhere does your question ask about energy and when it flows in or out of the capacitor or in or out of the rest of the circuit)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

An AC generator is considered low (or theoretically, zero) impedance, so it will "force" the capacitor connected to it to be at the same voltage at every point in time.

An important aspect of this circuit is what happens to the current in the capacitor during the different portions of the curve. For the first 90 degrees the voltage is rising, so current will go into the capacitor, and stop at the 90 degree point where the sine wave flattens out. From 90 to 180 (actually, to 270) degrees, current will go out of the capacitor and into the source of the wave. Presuming the diagram is of voltage, you can draw the current through the capacitor with a cosine wave. It starts at maximum at 0 degrees, then goes to zero at 90 degrees, and then goes negative for the next half-cycle from 90 to 270 degrees. From there it goes positive again to 360 degrees and the cycle repeats at 0 degrees.

What you may be thinking of is when a diode is in series with the AC source and a capacitor. In this case, the capacitor will charge up to the peak value in the first 90 degrees (minus the usual 0.6 volt drop of most silicon diodes) due to the AC voltage being greater than the capacitor voltage, and thus the diode being forward biased. After 90 degrees AC generator voltage drops, so the diode will be reversed biased, and no current will flow into or from the capacitor. It will stay charged at the peak voltage (again, minus the diode drop) of AC generator.

Comment: @Felthry, you are right. I got it.

Comment: @JohnCena if this answer fully covers your question, mark it as accepted(you as the asker get to decide which answer is correct) and if it helped and you felt it was well written, give user7291 an upvote.